# BLE Background scan is not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
manager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID.init(string: "FE50")], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])

<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>bluetooth-central</string>
    <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
</array>
```

I have turned background mode to on, and added [CBUUID] of services during scanning.

I can find the device from this service when I am in the foreground, 
but I can't find the device when I am in the background.

The app needs to be connected to a device with a door lock. If RSSI > -50 when scanning, open the door after connecting. If RSSI < -70, cancel the connection.
This behavior pattern is normal in the foreground, but it is not normal in the background.

Please give me some advice , I have been stuck for 1 week! I will be very grateful.

Comment: The `allowDuplicates` key doesn't operate in the background, so you will only get a single call to `didDiscover` for a given peripheral.

Comment: I know, but it don't call didDiscover in background.

Comment: Have you previously discovered the peripheral in the foreground before the app moved to the background?

Comment: Are you sure that this service is actually being advertised by the peripheral. Do you get a `didDiscover` call with this scanning line when your app is in the foreground.

Comment: I can find the device from this service when I am in the foreground.

Comment: Can you describe your testing process? e.g. App is terminated.  Peripheral is turned off.  Launch app. Press home to put app in background. Turn on peripheral.

Comment: The app needs to be connected to a device with a door lock. If RSSI > -50 when scanning, open the door after connecting. If RSSI < -70, cancel the connection.
This behavior pattern is normal in the foreground, but it is not normal in the background.

Comment: As I said in my first comment, you can't repeatedly scan in the background.  If a given peripheral has ever been discovered during the current execution of the app you won't get a `didDiscover` callback when it is in the background.  You would typically just have a pending `connect` that will complete in the background when the lock is in range.

Comment: Therefore, when I am in the background, I can't use RSSI to open or disconnect, right?

Comment: If you are connected you can issue a read RSSI but you can’t rely on the repeated RSSI indications you get in didDiscover

Comment: I found that the app can only read RSSI for a few seconds while in the background.

Comment: You can call `beginBackgroundTask` to get up to 3 minutes of background execution

Comment: I understand it approximately, thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think iOs only enables your background mod for a few mins. if you want to make it longer than an hour, you need to make some way around. This is a good [source](https://github.com/yarodevuci/backgroundTask) if you want to make it longer, but I won't be approved in the store I believe.

Comment: I correct my narrative and will not scan when I get to the background.

Comment: Have you declare what should it do at appplicationWillResignActive?

Comment: have not , what should i do at appplicationWillResignActive?